# JSON.parse not returning the orginal object

Tags: javascript, json

I am storing  a java script object in the `DB` by converting that into the string by using `JSON.stringify`, But when i want to retrieve that object from `DB` i use the `JSON.parse`. But the `JSON.parse` is not returning the original object. In the below console screenshot it can be seen that the object `Obj` had some changes after it is converted into string and then parsed. So how can i get back the original object after doing `JSON.stringify`

[image]

The Object is as below:

```
    var Obj =   {
                    onchange: function(){

                    },
                    validate: function(obj){

                    },
                    elements: {
                    "list": {
                    menu: [{
                    caption: "Append an",
                    action: Xonomy.newElementChild,
                    actionParameter: "dd"
                    }]
                    },
                    "item": {
                    menu: [{
                    caption: "Add ",
                    action: Xonomy.newAttribute,
                    actionParameter: {name: "label", value: "something"},
                    hideIf: function(jsElement){
                    return jsElement.hasAttribute("label");
                    }
                    }, {
                    caption: "Delete this ",
                    action: Xonomy.deleteElement
                    }, {
                    caption: "New  before this",
                    action: Xonomy.newElementBefore,
                    actionParameter: "sas"
                    }, {
                    caption: "New  after this",
                    action: Xonomy.newElementAfter,
                    actionParameter: "aa"
                    }],
                    canDropTo: ["list"],
                    attributes: {
                    "label": {
                    asker: Xonomy.askString,
                    menu: [{
                    caption: "Delete this",
                    action: Xonomy.deleteAttribute
                    }]
                    }
                    }
                    }
                    }
                    };
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: What changes are you worried about? You cannot express functions in JSON so they will be dropped no matter what.

Comment: Could you show us what you get after `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: {"elements":{"list":{"menu":"[{\"caption\": \"Append an\", \"actionParameter\": \"dd\"}]"},"item":{"menu":"[{\"caption\": \"Add @label=\\\"something\\\"\", \"actionParameter\": {\"name\": \"label\", \"value\": \"something\"}}, {\"caption\": \"Delete this \"}, {\"caption\": \"New  before this\", \"actionParameter\": \"sas\"}, {\"caption\": \"New  after this\", \"actionParameter\": \"aa\"}]","canDropTo":"[\"list\"]","attributes":{"label":{"menu":"[{\"caption\": \"Delete this @label\"}]"}}}}}

Comment: `function`s cannot be meaningfully `JSON.stringify`ed.

Comment: FIrst of all, that is not a valid JSON but a JS Object. Secondly, you can't pack functions in a JSON like this. They will be removed on stringify/parse. You can use function name references instead.

Comment: I am trying to implement the project in the repo https://github.com/michmech/xonomy.git for this i need some javascript object to be stored for allowing the user to edit the xml easily

Comment: @TusharShukla can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: function myFunc() { /* do Something */ } var obj = { "onChange": "myFunc" }; /* Call function like this */ obj.onChange();

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments - you can't serialize JS functions with JSON.stringify. Please take a look at [serialize-javascript](https://github.com/yahoo/serialize-javascript) library to store the functions.

Comment: I have added the index.js and require.js into my js directory, but it throws the error Module name "serialize-javascript" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) . Please explain me how to install that. Also where to enter the command $ npm install serialize-javascript

Comment: you can run "npm install" in root dir, should be downloaded to node_modules dir. there is a lot documentation on using of npm modules for your app, worth to go though simple tutorial and understand the main concepts.